# How to store Excel file using javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, excel, pdf

I have been trying to store an Excel file using Javascript but I cannot get it to work on all browsers. The first technique I used is BASE64 in combination with data URL. This works fine in Chrome and Firefox but IE en Safari don't work with this technique.

```
newlink = document.createElement('a');
newlink.setAttribute('href', 'data:application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet;base64,' + response.data);
newlink.setAttribute('download', 'test.xlsx');
newlink.click();
```

I also tried the Blob thingy.. but that doesn't seem to work properly with binary files like PDF, Excel and MS Word.

```
var report = response;
var str = atob(report.data);
var blob = new Blob([str], { type: report.type});
saveAs(blob, 'report.csv');
```

This works fine for a CSV file but when I do the same thing with Excel or Word the file is corrupted.

I am using AngularJS for doing the REST call and use token authentication through headers so simply using an URL and doing window.open(url) won't work since than you won't be authorized to perform that request. I tried both $resource and $http but with both I have the same result. The REST API works since when I make the URL public (no authentication needed) and go to the URL directly with my browser it downloads the file properly and I can open it. So it looks like something goes wrong when I create the Blob.

Does anybody have an idea how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

This is what I currently use:

arr is the array you want to be converted into the csv. Worked on IE/Chrome for me.

```
exportToCsv("export.csv",arr);

function exportToCsv(filename, rows) {
    var processRow = function (row) {
        var finalVal = '';
        for (var j = 0; j < row.length; j++) {
            var innerValue = row[j] === null ? '' : row[j].toString();
            if (row[j] instanceof Date) {
                innerValue = row[j].toLocaleString();
            };
            var result = innerValue.replace(/"/g, '""');
            if (result.search(/("|,|\n)/g) >= 0)
                result = '"' + result + '"';
            if (j > 0)
                finalVal += ',';
            finalVal += result;
        }
        return finalVal + '\n';
    };

    var csvFile = '';
    for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
        csvFile += processRow(rows[i]);
    }

    var blob = new Blob([csvFile], { type: 'text/csv;charset=utf-8;' });
    if (navigator.msSaveBlob) { // IE 10+
        navigator.msSaveBlob(blob, filename);
    } else {
        var link = document.createElement("a");
        if (link.download !== undefined) { // feature detection
            // Browsers that support HTML5 download attribute
            var url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
            link.setAttribute("href", url);
            link.setAttribute("download", filename);
            link.style = "visibility:hidden";
            document.body.appendChild(link);
            link.click();
            document.body.removeChild(link);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't have any issues with CSV files only with binary files. Also I am not generating the file on the client side. The file is generated on the server side and than returned in a REST call in a JSON response. The data part is encoded with BASE64. If I take that BASE64 string and convert it in a JUnit test and try to open the file it works fine. Which means the BASE64 string is correct so something goew wrong on the client side when transforming it back to binary format.